# Is there any component or possibility to create charts/diagrams/plots in NativeBase?

Tags: react-native, native-base, victory-charts

I have huge problem. I'm complitly new to ReactNative, and I am forced to transfer entire project to NativeBase (Because company bought a layout, and they HAVE TO used it...), and I'm fine with it, it looks really good so far. But, there is a but. Application which I'm currently developing needs to contains chars, like this:

[image]

And my probles is that template which I've got, doesn't want to install victory-native.
I've got errors like "This is related to npm not able to find a file" Some delegates file inside node_module directory.

There is any way to get charts with using nativeBase components?

Sorry if this is trivial question, but I couldn't find anything connected to this matter in google.
Thanks for your help.

And last question, Is that true that templates bought with nativeBase are open only do developers on Mac's and Linux? Why not windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I we manage to add Victory-charts library to the project, after "npm install sqlite3@3.1.8" and then npm install victory-chart. I don't know why this issue existed, but maybe it would be usefull for someone in future.